# Use MVC Session to store Client-side values (e.g. filter text) between visits

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session

In an MVC View, is there an efficient way to store client-side values for use on subsequent page visits?

**Typical scenario**

An Index page has a table that's getting a bit long so I add a filter (I know paging is another option) and use an input control with some JavaScript to limit the table rows without having to perform another "Get" from the server.

This works fine but, if I navigate off (say) into an edit page then return back to the Index page, the filter is clearly no longer there.

After a bit of searching I never found anything simple so I post my meagre answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The View contains a form at the top of the page into which a user can type filter text (on form "Get", text is set from a session value):-

```
<form id="frmEdit">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "nav-item nav-link" })
        </div>
        <label for="search" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">Filter</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" id="search" value=@Session["SparesSectionFilter"]>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

A script section contains the filtering JavaScript but also a postback to the controller

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // on load
        PerformFilter();

        // hook up events
        $(function () {
            $("input#search").on("keydown keyup", function () {
                PerformFilter();

                // post back to session for reuse
                $.post('SparesSections/Session_Add', { __RequestVerificationToken: $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(), itemName: 'SparesSectionFilter', itemValue: $("#search").val() });
            });
        })
   </script>
}
```

I have a custom base-class for my controller into which I've added the following actions. These are usable from any controller using this class. The Razor view loads the session value but I've included a "Get" in the controller for client-side options.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Session_Add(string itemName, string itemValue)
    {
        Session.Add(itemName, itemValue);

        return Json(new { itemName = itemName, itemValue = itemValue }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Session_Get(string itemName)
    {
        return Json(new { itemName = itemName, itemValue = Session[itemName] ?? string.Empty }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```